# Setting authentication properties in java soap client

Tags: java, soap

We're all familiar with doing authentication in a soap header

```
<soapenv:Header>
  <wsse:Security soapenv:mustUnderstand="1" xmlns:wsse="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-secext-1.0.xsd">
     <wsse:UsernameToken wsu:Id="UsernameToken-18" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd">
        <wsse:Username>userName</wsse:Username>
        <wsse:Password Type="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-username-token-profile-1.0#PasswordText">password</wsse:Password>
     </wsse:UsernameToken>
  </wsse:Security>
```

And imitating it in java using SOAPHandler. Unfortunately I have one web service where this just ends with a 401. The only way I can get a response in SOAP UI is using the username/password properties for the request.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/kwbbx.jpg

Pic of what I'm talking about in SOAPUI. The problem is I don't know how to set the properties that way in Java.

Answer (score 1):

When you set the username and password in those fields in SoapUI you are using [basic authentication](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication). This becomes a HTTP header named Authorization.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019997/preemptive-basic-auth-with-httpurlconnection).

Comment: Thanks. That answer didn't actually help, because I'm using autogen classes from wsimport, but it told me what to google.
This answer is what I ended up using:
http://stackoverflow.com/a/7086636/2561658