# converting cURL to Android request

Tags: java, android, http

This question has been asked a lot, but most of the answers use the deprecated Android HTTPClient. Can someone help me rewrite the following GET request for Android/Java?

```
curl -u r0fls:12345 -i -X GET http://192.168.0.2/api/token
```

I was able to do a POST from Android to the server successfully, to create a new user, which I can show if that will be helpful. It took about 25 lines of Java though.

Comment: 25 lines sounds about right for an `HttpURLConnection` implementation, assuming that is what you are using. If you got that `POST` working, what is it about this `GET` request that you do not understand?

Comment: I tried simply switching `connection.setRequestMethod("POST");` to `connection.setRequestMethod("GET");` and the URL. The`POST` request that works is to create a new user, so it sends the same data as the one for a token (username/password).

Comment: ... but the cURL post format is a bit different. It specifies `'application/json'` content-type, which I did not remove or alter for the `GET` request.

Comment: It's still trying to do a `POST` request after I switch to `setRequestMethod('GET')`.

Comment: Then try removing it. For HTTP basic authentication, a Google search for `java httpurlconnection basic authentication example` turns up lots of hits, such as http://stackoverflow.com/questions/496651/connecting-to-remote-url-which-requires-authentication-using-java and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019997/preemptive-basic-auth-with-httpurlconnection. "It's still trying to do a POST request after I switch to setRequestMethod('GET')" -- consider editing your question and posting your code.

Comment: thanks, I got it working using your links.