# IOException in Basic Authentication for HTTP url

Tags: java, basic-authentication

I am hitting HTTP url with username:password using JAVA code. Below is my code

```
public static main (String args[]){
try{ 

                    String webPage = "http://00.00.000.000:8080/rsgateway/data/v3/user/start/";
        String name = "abc001";
        String password = "abc100";
        String authString = name + ":" + password;
        System.out.println("auth string: " + authString);
        byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());
        String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);
        URL url = new URL(webPage);
                    HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();
            connection.setUseCaches(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        connection.setRequestProperty("Authorization","Basic " +authStringEnc);
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Accept", "application/xml");
                    connection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type", "application/xml");
        InputStream is = connection.getInputStream();
        InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is);

        int numCharsRead;
        char[] charArray = new char[1024];
        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();
        while ((numCharsRead = isr.read(charArray)) > 0) {
            sb.append(charArray, 0, numCharsRead);
        }
        String result = sb.toString();

        System.out.println("*** BEGIN ***");
        System.out.println(result);
        System.out.println("*** END ***");
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But I am getting 401 Error

> java.io.IOException: Server returned HTTP response code: 401 for URL:

same url if i hit using curl then it is returning response. below is the curl command.

> curl -u abc001:abc100 http://00.00.000.000:8080/rsgateway/data/v3/user/start/

Please help me resolve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you are getting is HTTP `401 Unauthorized`, which means that the server isn't interpreting your basic authentication properly.

Since you say that the `curl` command with the basic authentication you showed is working, I'll assume the problem is in your code.

It looks like you tried to follow [this code.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7019997/preemptive-basic-auth-with-httpurlconnection)

The only error I can see (but I cannot test this to be sure) is that you just cast the `byte[]` to a `String` instead of encoding it with `Base64`.

So you should change ***this:***

`String authStringEnc = new String(authEncBytes);`

***to this:***

`String authStringEnc = Base64.getEncoder().encodeToString(authEncBytes);`

Also, you want to change ***this:***

`byte[] authEncBytes = Base64.encodeBase64(authString.getBytes());`

***to this:***

`byte[] authEncBytes = authString.getBytes();`

<strike>`byte[] authEncBytes = authString.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8);`</strike>

Comment: I am getting error on **StandardCharsets.UTF_8** . I imported java.io.IOException but error on UTF_8

Comment: In that case you can just get the bytes of the string without specifying the charset.  See my updated answer.